# Updating View in Angular js on ajax success callback

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am working on a project where I am getting list of the offers from a service.
Each offer is Active or Inactive. I am displying only Active offers on a view on tabular format by giving ajax call and using ng-repeat.

When I click on the link **Inactivate Offer**
then I am giving another ajax request to inactivate that offer in database. So once I inactivate offer it should not be displyed on view. 
My code to fect offer and Inactivate the offer is :

```
    mPosServices.factory('mosServiceFactory',function($http,$rootScope){
   return{
       viewAllOffers:function(){
           var allOffers = $http({
                        method: "get",
                        url: "http://myServiceUrl/omnichannel/merchant/offer/view/all?enrollmentId="+$rootScope.enrollMentId,
                    });
               return allOffers;     
       },

       inActivateOffer : function(id){
           var inactivate = $http({
               method:'get',
               url : "http://myServiceUrl/omnichannel/merchant/offer/"+id+"/status/INACTIVE?enrollmentId="+$rootScope.enrollMentId,
           });
           return inactivate;
       }
   } 
});
```

and controller code is to fect the offers and inactivate offer is :

```
var mPosController = angular.module('mPosController', []);

mPosController.controller('offerController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'mosServiceFactory', 'ngDialog', function ($scope, $rootScope, mosServiceFactory, ngDialog) {
  mosServiceFactory.viewAllOffers().then(function (data) {
            $scope.offers = data.data.offers;
            console.log($scope.offers);
        });

    $scope.inActivate = function (id) {
        mosServiceFactory.inActivateOffer(id).then(function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
      }
    }]);
```

Offer is getting successfully inactivated in response of $scope.inActivate method but that perticular offer is still visible in view.

So how to display on Active offers once I inactivate a offer using service call ?

Comment: probably wrap that `$scope.offers = data.data.offers` in a `$scope.$applyAsync(function () { });` because you are outside of the digest cycle - which means angular can't pick up the change! Or just call `$scope.$apply()` after that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly performs a `GET` request to inactivate the offer, however you do not "tell" Angular that the offer has been inactivated. What you need to do is remove the offer from the offers list `$scope.offers` once the offer is successfully inactivated (ie. when the `inActivateOffer` promise is resolved).  You could try something like this:

```
$scope.inActivate = function (id) {
    mosServiceFactory.inActivateOffer(id).then(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.offers.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.offers[i].id === id) {
                $scope.offers.splice(i, 1);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked.

I did some other thing like when the inActivateOffer promise is resolved i broadcasted a msg  that offer has been inactive using $rootScope.$broadcast and listen this broadcasted msg in controller using $on and again called the service mosServiceFactory.viewAllOffers() .

I guess my solution in not relevent as its giving unnecessary service call